# Raspberry Pi 2 wont turn on, just blinking green

Tags: boot

I just got my Raspberry disconnected from a 1 meter USB cable and then connect an extension USB cable (about 2 meters). Before replacing the cable the Raspberry functioned normally, but after replacing the cable, the green LED flashes and nothing happens. I tried 2 chargers: one 1A and through the gate with a second outlet with Raspberry 2A but this does not have any effect.

Comment: Does it work when connected to a short cable?  If so the long cables are probably losing too much voltage.

Comment: Yes! with short cable it work perfectly.. I wondered over low voltage but do not know how to check .. I have a strain gauge, but I do not know how to measure voltage usb

Comment: Well, by experiment you have discovered the long cables lose too much voltage.  Buy chunkier cables, USB cable wires can be very thin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the current draw over USB, then there are many types of USB voltmeter/ammeters [available on eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR8.TRC0.A0.H0.Xusb%20voltmeter.TRS0&_nkw=usb%20voltmeter&_sacat=0), for example:

[image: USB Voltmeter]

This may help you track down the problem. However, as joan suggests in the [comments](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33974/raspberry-pi-2-wont-turn-on-just-blinking-green#comment-44495), if you *must* use a 2 meter cable then get a thicker USB cable, so that there is less power drop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have pretty much done the troubleshooting yourself, the problem is most likely in the cable. It could be a really low quality one, since moving from 1A to 2A doesn't change a thing. Maybe the cable is even broken.

You could try and see of the extension cable works with connecting i.e. your phone to a PC (if it's that kind of cable).

The longer the cable the less efficient it will be, so might as well go for a proper one in your case!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply,

Problem was not resolved,but it was in cable. I have found better cable and everything is now okay.